# Cake php upgrade showing error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0, upgrade

I am new in cake php development, I have done a cake php upgrade from 2.7.5 to latest version 3. but i have some issues, when i try to run bin/cake server it shows below errors.

> PHP Warning:  include(Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/project_1/bin/cake.php on line 31 PHP Warning:  include():
>   Failed opening 'Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/var/www/lib:.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/project_1/bin/cake.php on line 31
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Could not locate CakePHP core files. in
>   /var/www/project_1/bin/cake.php on line 32

I can see the file cake.php which does not have any change but all other files moved from app to src folder, using cake php upgrade tool

Comment: If these files haven't changed, then you probably didn't run the upgrade tool correctly/completely, as its skeleton task would replace them (which may require enabling the `overwrite` option - make sure that you backup your files!).

Comment: I have run the command  from cake 3version (bin/cake upgrade all /var/www/project_1/) @ndm can you help me on this.

Comment: That means that you did not run the `skeleton` task, as it's not included in `all`, check the help, it mentions that you must run it manually (_all Run all tasks except for skeleton. That task should only be run manually, and only for apps (not plugins)_). Again, backup your files before running that task!

Comment: I have run the skeleton after the upgrade all command but still same issue persists

Comment: Sounds like you probably did not enable overwriting.

Comment: How can I enable the overwriting